# How to load CSS on SSL pages?

Tags: css, ssl

I am using relative paths to my CSS document, but on the SSL pages the document will not load. Navigating back to the non-SSL pages brings SSL back.  How to I overcome this?

Comment: Is your SSL and non-SSL site using the same data? Or are they handled within different virtual hosts/directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using relative paths with SSL pages, there must be something else involved.

Have you considered any other logic you may have, an extra redirect with different URL, or anything else that could be causing it?

PS. If you are using [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), hit view source and Ctrl-click on the CSS path. It should take you to what it's supposed to be pointing at.

Comment: you are correct. IIS rewrite was forcing the css link back to non-ssl.