# Having relative image urls in css load over ssl without absolute url

Tags: css, ssl

The title pretty much explains it all I'm currently loading my css over ssl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/dist/stylesheet/dist.css?=v2.1.2">
```

Inside my css I am loading a lot of background images like so

```
.sec6 .block-3 {
  background: url(/dist/images/department/bags_jewelry/sec6_b3.jpg);
}
```

Is it possible to have these images load over `ssl` without me having to write in the absolute url for all of them?

Comment: afaik the relative path is relative to the address you are currently in. So if you browse `https://yourdomain.com` then your images will be loaded via SSL. As a side note, (not directly relevant to your question) a good way to load resources on the current protocol is to use `href="://example.com/... `

Comment: agreed with @BartCalixto, you can see it in the inspector of your browser, in the network section, unless you are using self made SSL certificate, where the browser will block it because it cannot trust the certificate. Try to add your certificate to the browser white list.

Comment: That's what my speculation was I just unfortunately cant `ssl` my whole site as of yet:(

Comment: i think your problem is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830912/how-to-load-css-on-ssl-pages?rq=1